# Can't access MySQL through terminal anymore

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and was able to log in and mess around with it the other day. I must have done something because now when I try to login doing `mysql -u root -p`, I get the following error message:

> -bash: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql: No such file or directory.

Any ideas on what to do please

Comment: Sounds like you don't have MAMP installed anymore. Perhaps you uninstalled it?

Comment: I went ahead and downloaded MAMP again and now I am getting this as my error. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) I tried to run /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p but I still get the same error

Comment: Well now it's able to find the mysql client program, which is progress. But it sounds like the MySQL Server is not running. Did you open the MAMP app and start the servers? See https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/First-Steps/

Comment: I got the server running now and now when I try mysql -u root -p and put in my password I get the following error message ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). I have read multiple scenarios on how to fix this one starting MySQL in safe mode and trying to change the root password but it doesn't seem to work because I still keep getting the error.

Comment: Some versions of MySQL generate a random password for root when you install. You can check `/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err` (I think) to see if the password it generated is logged there.

Comment: I tried it and it gave me -bash: /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err: No such file or directory

Comment: There are also good step-by-step instructions for resetting the password here: https://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/ Be sure to read to the end, it gives an alternative method for MySQL 5.7. So it depends which version you are using.

Comment: Try mysql -h localhost -u root -p

Comment: thank you! the step-by-step instructions worked.